Magento 2.4.2 : Multi select options for customer custom Attribute is not update
Update in admin panel is not update the values
<?php
namespace Gem\PaymentMethodRestriction\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class InstallData implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();

        /** @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        // Add the customer attribute with the payment options
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'allowed_payment_methods',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Allowed Payment Methods',
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'system' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'source' => \Gem\PaymentMethodRestriction\Model\Attribute\Source\AllowedPaymentMethods::class,
            ]
        );

        // Make the attribute available in the customer forms
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'allowed_payment_methods')
            ->addData([
                'used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit'
                ],
            ]);
        $attribute->save();

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }
    
    public function getVersion()
    {
        return '1.0.0';
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'allowed_payment_methods');
        
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}


Update your code with this :
$customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'allowed_payment_methods',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Allowed Payment Methods',
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'system' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'source' => Gem\PaymentMethodRestriction\Model\Attribute\Source\AllowedPaymentMethods
            ]
        );

Now create AllowedPaymentMethods.php file on the following paths.
<?php

namespace Gem\PaymentMethodRestriction\Model\Attribute\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

class AllowedPaymentMethods extends AbstractSource
{
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        return [
            'option1' => [
                'label' => 'Option 1',
                'value' => 'option1'
            ],
            'option2' => [
                'label' => 'Option 2',
                'value' => 'option2'
            ],
            'option3' => [
                'label' => 'Option 3',
                'value' => 'option3'
            ],
            'option4' => [
                'label' => 'Option 4',
                'value' => 'option4'
            ]
        ];
    }
}


it is not working value is not updated

in frontend also the attribute also not coming using customer model

in your option which which value you are using?
